# Mark all the previously selected items from a ListView in an other Color when returning from activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, colors, hashmap

I am using a ListView in combination with a HashList to show data from an SQL Database through JSON. Everything works fine. But now I want to have a special feature.

In the ListView are round about 400 Items. So if i click one of the item to view its content and switch via Backbutton back to the Listview, i want to have the viewed Item from the Listview being marked in another color so that the user sees directly which oh the items he already has clicked.

I painted an little grafik for you, for better understanding

[image]

On the left side, the original View. After i View the 1st,5th and 8th Item of the list, the list should look like at the right side.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own adapter, then have an boolean array to store the current status of every row, and in the getView function assign a different color to the background of the selected rows based on your boolean array.

For this you will need also to set an onClick event in your rows to open the previsualization view and there also check the boolean array as "visited".

For more info about how to make custom efficient adapters, please read [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

---

To simply let the user choice more than one row you can use

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

in your list

Comment: Thanks, but this will give the opportunity to mark multiply entries of the list if I got this right. But the User should still be able to select only one item from the List. :/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you right the first time, I'll edited my answer